# How can I show different tables based on a particular row value group?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ag-grid

So I have a json data which is something like this:

```
[
{ "fruit":"apple",
  "country": "A"
},
{ "fruit":"banana",
  "country": "b"
},
{ "fruit":"apple",
  "country": "C"
},
{ "fruit":"banana",
  "country": "D"
}]
```

For now it's all in the same table. But what I want to do is group the data by fruit and show different tables which in this case would generate two tables, where in first table there would be two rows for apple and in the second table there would be two rows for banana. So if there are 5 types of fruits then there should be five tables with their respective data. How can I do this? I tried using *ngFor loop to loop through the data but I'm stuck at this point as to how can I group it and show different tables? Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some modification for data might be helpful.

```
const mapData = new Map<string, string[]>();
this.data.forEach(value => {
  const fruit = value.fruit;
  const country = value.country;
  if (!mapData.has(fruit)) {
    mapData.set(fruit, []);
  }

  mapData.get(fruit).push(country);
});
```